# Is there a way I can get output from two if conditions?

Tags: python, windows

I'm starting with Python and I'm very connected to the language but I have a small problem, when I try to check if the user is a male or tall, the program works fine.

But when I try to check if the user is a male and not tall, the program prints only the first.

```
is_male = True
is_tall = False


if is_male or is_tall:
     print ("You are a male or tall or both")

elif is_male and not (is_tall):
     print ("You are a male but not tall")

else:
     print ("You are not a male or tall!")
```

The output I get is: "You are a male or tall or both"

The output I aim for, first condition and: "You are a male but not tall"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Comment: You want a series of if statements, not if...elif.

Comment: Your first `if` covers three of the four possibilities of `is_male, is_tall`. This means that the `elif` will never match.

Comment: @Raphael Can you please explain me instead of throwing me a website?

Comment: @quamrana Isn't this `elif` matches the `else if` in C ++ language?
So why doesn't it work in python?

Comment: if all your statements have if, and if all of them were true, all of them will execute. But if you have if and elif, then it will stop with first statement that is executed.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do (and it would do exactly the same thing in C++).  The logic you want is not `else if` logic.  See the previous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your if conditions. The problem is, that the second can't be reached with your approach, because of its logical equation would be:

`(not (is_male or is_tall)) and (is_male and not is_tall) 
= (not is_male and is_tall) and is_male and not is_tall) 
= (is_tall) and (is_male and not is_male) 
= False` 
Just some logical rules based on [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). The first condition exists because you have an `elif` so the first if condition must be False.

Or in simple words: *every time you have a male the first condition is True*.

Possible restructure solutions:

- Nest the conditions
- Only use if conditions

**Nested conditions**

```
if is_male:
    if is_tall:
        print("male and tall")
    else:
        print("Male but not tall")
else:
    if is_tall:
        print("not male and tall")
    else:
        print("not male and not tall")
```

**Only if statements**

```
if male and tall:
     print("male and tall")
if male and not tall:
     print("male and not tall")
if not male and tall:
     print("not male and tall")
if not male and not tall:
     print("not male and not tall")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will cover all your possibilities:

```
if is_male or is_tall:
     print ("You are a male or tall or both")

if is_male and is_tall:
    pass
elif not is_male and is_tall:
    pass
elif is_male and not (is_tall):
     print ("You are a male but not tall")
else:
     print ("You are not a male or tall!")
```

The first `if` just covers `is_male or is_tall` as a separate statement.

Answer (score 0):

For every print use if condition (without elif)

```
is_male = True
is_tall = False


if is_male or is_tall:
     print ("You are a male or tall or both")

if is_male and not is_tall:
     print ("You are a male but not tall")

if not is_male and not is_tall:
     print ("You are not a male or tall!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty simple. An "else" or "elif" can only be executed if the preceding "if"s and "elif"s didn't execute.

In other words, Python looks at your code like this:

- `if is_male or is_tall:` "Okay, `is_male` is true, so the `or` is true, so the `if` is satisfied."
- `print ("You are a male or tall or both")`: "Okay, the if was satisfied, so I should do this. Printing `You are a male or tell or both` now."
- `elif is_male and not (is_tall)`: "Okay, this is an else, and the previous if was satisfied, so I won't look at this."
- `else`: "Okay, this is an else, and the previous if was satisfied, so I won't look at this."

If you want both messages to be printed, you need to separate them.

```
if is_male or is_tall:
    print ("You are a male or tall or both");
if is_male and not (is_tall):
    print ("You are male but not tall");
if not (is_male) and not (is_tall):
    print ("You are not a male or tall");
```

Answer (score -2):

You have it in the wrong Order, the first 'if' only needs (is_male) to be true that's  why always prints "You are a male or tall or both".

try:

```
is_male = True
is_tall = False


if is_male and not (is_tall):
     print ("You are a male but not tall")

elif is_male or is_tall:
     print ("You are a male or tall or both")

else:
     print ("You are not a male or tall!")
```

Comment: The question asks for multiple things to be printed ("You are a male or tall or both" AND "You are a male but not tall").